# How to prevent someone exposing my murder scheme in CK3?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I got drunk at a feast and divulged a murder secret to my neice. I'm on very good terms with her and even know 2 weak hook secrets on her but she keeps exposing me no matter what I do.

I have saves enabled so I keep reloading to try to sway her and send her gifts but it doesn't seem to stop the exposure. Is there anything I can do to prevent this?
Obviously I could murder her or imprison her but I'd rather let her continue to rule her county if possible.

Comment: Is it an ongoing murder scheme or is it about a murder you committed in the past?

Comment: What are her personality traits?

Answer (score 2):

Because I should not answer in comments, here are some suggestions and ideas:

First of all, as @RavenDreamer commented, her personality traits likely matter a lot here. A honest person likely is much harder to convince to look the other way than a cynical one.

Have you tried giving her a reason to spend the hook on? E.g. if you raise her taxes using your hooks on her, maybe she'll use her hook to lower them back.

If nothing like that works, killing her to cover your tracks might be the only option left. Although that may the start of your highway to hell, when during the next feast... ;)

The bottom line of course is: Don't do the crime if you don't want to face potential consequences. Or at least, don't go to feasts while your murder plan is executing to minimize the risk.

I like it that CK3 always forces one to weight the advantages against the disadvantages. There barely seems any free lunch in the game - even a free feast can have negative side effects! :)